# Como mostrar los datos con formatos en un pdf

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Yo tengo un `textarea` con un editor para enviar datos con formatos tales como en negritas, viñetas, etc y cuando muestro esos datos en un pdf me los muestra de la siguiente manera:

```
<p><b>LUGAR: </b>En estudio</p><p><b>CAPELLÁN:</b> En estudio</p><p>OBJETIVO DE
```

No me los muestras con el formato. Estoy usando `dompdf`, `laravel` y `angular`.

Asi hago la llamada a `dompdf`:

```
public function crearPDF($datos, $actividades, $vistaurl, $tipo){
    $data = $datos;
    $actividades = $actividades;
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $view = \View::make($vistaurl, compact('data', 'actividades', 'date'))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);

    if($tipo==1){
        return $pdf->stream('reporte.pdf');
    }
    if($tipo==2){
        return $pdf->download('reporte.pdf');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pon como haces la llamada a dompdf y los parámetros que le pasas.

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando una vista para cargarla con dompdf entoces usa el facade **PDF** con el método **loadView**:

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView($vistaurl, ['data' => $data, 'actividades' => $actividades, 'date' => $date]);
```